# How to make extensible Eloquent models?

Tags: php, laravel, one-to-many, relationship, eloquent

How to add to an Eloquent model without modifying its source code? By that i mean lets say i have a User model and i want to add a has_many relationship to ProfilePost but i don't want to modify the User model. I would like to do this because later on, 3rd party developers can also add their relationships to my User model without having to change the source code for my User model. What is the accepted solution for this? I have been looking at a onetomany relationship  but i still have to add a belongs_to clause in the User model.

What is the accepted solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

is the solution developers create a new User model, extended your User Model.

**Your User Model**

```
<?php namespace \App\Models;

use Eloquent;

class User extends Eloquent {}
```

**3rd party developers User Model**

```
<?php namespace \custom_lib\Models;

use \App\Models\User as BaseUser;

class User extends BaseUser {}
```

now in \custom_lib\Models\User, the 3rd party developers can add the relations of his lib/plugin.

Comment: This still has a problem where a devs extends the user model but the code already written will use the old one. Ive been looking at the IOC container for this but it doesn't feel extensible enough. Any ideas?